# How many actions on average to complete described coloring balls game?

Tags: combinatorics

To start with we have $x$ white balls in a bag. We perform an action on them in the following way: we pick a ball at random and if it's white we paint it black and put it back in a bag. If it's black we don't do anything to it, just put it back in a bag. We continue performing actions until all balls are black.

How many actions on average does it take to finish?

Comment: This is a variation of the coupon collector problem. Check https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

Comment: @AspiringMat that's helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the number of balls we need to take out of the bag so that we color all the balls black. Define a random variable $X_i$ such that it counts the number of balls we need to take out until we get a white ball when there are $i-1$ black balls in the bag. Clearly, you can see the relation:

$X=\sum_{i=1}^x{X_i}$   and by the linearity of expectation $\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum_{i=1}^x\mathbb{E}(X_i) \quad (*)$.

Now consider $X_i$, it can be treated as a geometric distribution with a success when we draw a white ball and a failure when we draw a black ball. The probability of success each time is $\frac{x-i+1}{x}$. We know the expectation of a geometric random variable is given by $\frac{1}{p}$ where $p$ is the probability of success so we have:

$\mathbb{E}(X_i)=\frac{1}{\frac{x-i+1}{x}}=\frac{x}{x-i+1}$. Subbing this into $(*)$ we get $\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum_{i=1}^x(\frac{x}{x-i+1})=x\sum_{i=1}^x\frac{1}{x-i+1}=x\sum_{i=1}^x\frac{1}{i}=xH_x$ where $H_x$ is the harmonic partial sum.

Also, if you want to get an approximation on this, we know that $xH_x \leq x(\ln(x)+1)=x\ln(x)+x$ which is an upper bound on how long this process will roughly take.